# Finding the Angle between Vanishing point and Lines in Python

Tags: python, opencv, line, angle, vanishing-point

I am working on a project in which I need to first find the vanishing point in an image and the angle the vanishing point makes with the lines. I have done finding the vanishing point. How should I find the angle i.e theta1 and theta2

Consider I have the X and Y coordinates of vanishing point

[here is the image link of the test image with vanishing point and the angles to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIyT0.png)

Comment: Do you only have the coordinates to the vanishing point? I'm not sure if that is enough info

Comment: So you mean angle between line and horizon line? Do you assume the horizon line to be horizontal (parallel to x axis) all the time?

Comment: you're gonna need to give more information. I don't see why you'd be stuck with this. calculating angles, given *any* formulation of those lines, isn't a challenge. the challenge here is getting you to explain why it is.

Comment: @LancesLance Yes, I only have coordinates of vanishing point

Comment: @Micka Yes, assuming horizon to be parallel to x axis all time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.